# popup show only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to generate popup only once . current popup is not working .
I am new here so I am unable to manage this. nay help please

Here is my jquery code. I do not know why this is not working .please help

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            if (localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown') {
                $("#popup").delay(2000).fadeIn();
                localStorage.setItem('popState', 'shown')
            }
        
            $('#popup-close').click(function (e) // You are clicking the close button
            {
                $('#popup').fadeOut(); // Now the pop up is hiden.
            });
            $('#popup').click(function (e) {
                $('#popup').fadeOut();
            });
        });
```

```css
 div{
        height : 50px;
        background-color:blue;
    }
```

```html
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="modal fade" id="popup" >
          <div  class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="model-image">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="popup-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
               
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="model-titles"> <div class="delivery"></div></div>
                <div class="custom-discount"> <div class="amt"></div></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: You probably want `id="popup"` not `id="#popup"` (no #). Same for `class="#popup-close"`

Comment: j08691 @ ok thanks right now poup is working. but it coming evering time after browsing . And I am trying to generate poup only once on based on user session

Comment: then store a variable in user session ?

Comment: Thomas Kleßen@well can i do this  with java-script. only one time open  in open browser

Comment: @hacknext This will only show the modal once. If you use css to set it to `display: none;`, it'll only show once. Fire up this fiddle and look at your console. It'll say localStorage item has been set. Click it the run button to run the code again and you won't be able to see the modal fade in unless you delete the localStorage item: https://jsfiddle.net/jvb3w8Ly/1/

Comment: Did you check out that fiddle? Basically the gist here is to look to see if the localStorage item exists. If it does not exist, it will fade in the hidden modal div and set the localStorage item so you will only see it once. Also to see the item get set, open your console up, click on the application tab and click on localStore and you can see the storage item as well as its value.

Comment: I just gave you a step by step guide of what the code does. I don't think I can explain it any simpler than that. Which part is confusing you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close here. I would set the modal div to `display: none` because right now, no matter if the `localStorage` item is set or not, it'll always be visible. Here's what I would do.

CSS:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('popState', 'value') != 'shown') {
  $("#popup").delay(2000).fadeIn();
  localStorage.setItem('popState', 'shown');
  console.log('localstorage item set.');
} else {
    console.log('No modal for you.');
}

$('#popup-close').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#popup').fadeOut(); // Now the pop up is hiden.
});

$('#popup').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#popup').fadeOut();
});
```

With this code, you will check to see it the popstate value is set, if it is not set, it will fade in the modal after that two second mark, set the `localStorage` item and will log "localStorage item set" to the console. If you would reload the page you were using this on, you would see "No modal for you." get logged to the console. The `console.log` items are just for testing purposes so when you are ready to use this code in a production setting, I'd remove those.